# Can you extract bytesn from bytes in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, bytes

How would you create a Solidity function with the following signature?

```
function extract(bytes data) returns (bytes20 subdata)
```

Where `subdata` is a contiguous slice of `data` and `data.length > 20`.

This can be with or without inline assembly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I've got so far (for the specific case of `n=20`):

```
function extract(bytes data, uint pos) returns (bytes20) {
    uint160 subdata = 0;
    for (uint160 i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        subdata += uint160(data[i + pos]) * 2 ** (8 * (19 - i));
    }
    return bytes20(subdata);
}
```

Drawbacks:

1. limited to `n=20`
2. expensive to compute the powers each time the function is called
3. verbose compared to slicing

Point (2) can be addressed by pre-computing the powers of two (e.g. at contract instantiation). I don't think it is possible to overcome (1) at present in Solidity as return types are strict.

Answer (score 1):

Just an analogue. Not so expensive.

```
function extract(bytes data, uint pos) constant
returns (bytes20 result)
{ 
    for (uint i=0; i<20;i++)
        result^=(bytes20(0xff00000000000000000000000000000000000000)&data[i+pos])>>(i*8);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit cleaner now we have bitshift ops :)

Comment: Whats the purpose of the `bytes20(0xff...)`?

Comment: To create a constant with exactly size of 20 bytes. I'm not sure if it is nessesury. But I'm sure it wil work right.